# Moving layers on a XAML Canvas control: slow performances

Tags: c#, performance, xaml, windows-phone-7, canvas

In my Windows Phone 7 application there is a page with a main `Canvas` control. It contains 5 `Image` layers with size 640x480 and some transparency, stacked up one above the other.

At start, the application reads the information coming from the accelerometer and moves the Images at different positions at every X;Y;Z update.

I use the `Canvas.SetLeft(element, position)` and `Canvas.SetTop(element, position)` methods to move each layer separately, like that:

```
void accelSensor_CurrentValueChanged(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
{
   accelReading.X = (float)e.SensorReading.Acceleration.X;
   accelReading.Y = (float)e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Y;
   accelReading.Z = (float)e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Z;

   /* do some math... */

   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < MainCanvas.Children.Count; i++)
      {
         Canvas.SetLeft(MainCanvas.Children[i], /* some value... */));
         Canvas.SetTop(MainCanvas.Children[i], /* some value... */));
      }
   });
}
```

The problem is that the GUI is updated very very slowly... the objects change their positions like once per second. Have I implemented the wrong method? What's the right way to move Images very ofter without losing FPS? Do I really need to switch to XNA?

Comment: Did you try with a TranslateTransform? I think that Transforms are performed by the GPU.

Comment: I will give it a try. So I just need to change the way I tell the layers how to move, but they are always in a Canvas?

Comment: Bad news: I tried to use TranslateTransform with very similar results. Also, I tried to stack all the layers inside a Grid instead of a Canvas, same slow movements.

Comment: First, can you test the performance in a situation we're sure GPU acceleration is used? Remove the accelerator reading, and make your layers move on a predefined way by using storyboards with translate-transforms (do not change manually the properties of the translate-transforms, let the storyboard take care of everything)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the accelerometer's fault. There is also a method that resets the position of the layers when the uset taps on the Canvas. Here, nothing is related to the accelerometer but the layers move to the "0;0" position after a while too.

Comment: Why are you dispatching like that? I can gurantee you that this will kill your performance very quickly if the value changed method is called frequently. You are flooding the dispatcher with jobs. The best way would be to use animations.

Comment: Could you be more precise about the use of animations instead of a dispatcher call? I think that the dispatcher is still required to start animations from another thread... Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that the GPU is accelarated set Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true; in App.xaml.cs and check that the whole screen is not colored (surface not hardwware accelarated will be colored).
You can combine that by also setting Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true; to see what surface are being redrawed.
To get the benefit of hardware acccelaration when changing properties in code (and not in storyboard) make sure to set CacheMode="BitmapCache" on the object you move.

Comment: IT WORKS!! Setting EnableCacheVisualization to true shows a blue layer on the whole Canvas, while setting CacheMode="BitmapCache" on the control produce a much faster rendering!
Saviour badge for you.